# Android: (simple) missing import or...?

Tags: android, android-widget, listener, actionlistener

I am following a book to learn Android and am getting an error, this is my code[image: code with error]

I am using an image above so you can see the error as well (compoundbutton).

Did I type something wrong or did the book not write some of the imports needed?

Thanks!

EDITED full code:

```
package newbook.appress;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;

public class CheckBoxDemo extends Activity 
implements CompoundButton.OnCheckChangedListener{

    CheckBox cb;

     @Override 
      public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) { 
        super.onCreate(icicle); 
        setContentView(R.layout.main); 

        cb=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.chkBox1);
        cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
     }


     public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, 
             boolean isChecked) { 
        if (isChecked) { 
        cb.setText("This checkbox is: checked"); 
        } 
        else { 
        cb.setText("This checkbox is: unchecked"); 
        } 
        }

}
```

Comment: I'm assuming this is eclipse, what does the error say when you hover your mouse over the red part?

Comment: Yep, "compoundButton cannot be resolved to a type"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is correct. you need to import everything. You are missing:

```
    import android.widget.CompoundButton
```

You can type:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to **O** rganize your imports automatically in Eclipse.

You'll also want to change the second error to:

```
cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
```

Comment: Ok, did that and it added CompoundButton to the import list but it still has the errors and it says "CompoundButton.OnCheckChangedListener cannot be resolved to a type"

Comment: Ryan, the correct class name is CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener, not CompoundButton.OnCheckChangeListener :)